# How to programatically perform image segmentation in real-time

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I am currently trying to segment ultrasound images of blood vessels (video frames), such as the one directly below.

Using a simple binary filter on the saturation channel (code below), I can get a nonsatisfactory result such as the 3rd image below. Of course, I tried to dilate the filtered region a few pixels with OpenCV `Imgproc.dilate()`, but the problem with that is that it increases the chance to join the filtered region with neighboring black regions a lot, which causes a unacceptable precision loss in the subsequent calculations.

If someone who has experience in this kind of segmentation would be kind enough to point me to a good technique to achieve something approaching the 2nd image below in real-time (30 frames/sec), that would be really nice!

---

How to segment this base image:

[image: base image]

So it looks more like this hand-drawn segmentation:

[image: human segmented image]

While a simple binary filter on the saturation channel is not that good:

[image: saturation-filtered image]

My saturation filtering function (java):

```
public static Mat threshold_onsat (Mat frame, Mat hsv_frame, int saturation){
    double sat = (double) saturation;
    List<Mat> lhsv = new ArrayList<Mat>(3);
    Mat masked = new Mat();
    Core.split(hsv_frame, lhsv);
    Mat sat_mask = lhsv.get(1);
    Imgproc.threshold(sat_mask, sat_mask, sat, 255D, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    frame.copyTo(masked, sat_mask);
    return masked;
}
```

Comment: This is really cool and the question is all right, but just want to point out a thing: I have a friend doing a PhD in a quite similar topic. What I want to say is that you may not get an answer to this question, if there are people that will work 3 years at least to get something like this working properly. Good luck

Comment: As suggestion: search the literature for image segmentation in medicine. Level sets are a common approach.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes I do realize that. However, I thought it worthwhile to ask anyway. No cost in trying, right? :-) Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Choose the center of gravity of your automatic segmentation as your starting point. From there shoot rays to the outside and plot the intensity values. MaMaybe you see some "pattern changes" around the region where your manual segmentation is placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be wanting to take a look at a more complex method called active shapes. While I'm not an expert at medical image processing, I know a friend of mine has successfully used this method for the segmentation of inner and outer surface of abdominal aneurysms (ouch) which seems to be loosely related to your application. You can find some more information on the topic [in this paper](http://www.sci.utah.edu/~gerig/CS7960-S2010/handouts/ivc95.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can stick with your current saturation filter since it identifies your region. BUT then augment it using morphological operations. I would use erosion followed by dilation. (not just dilation on its own as you tried). The erosion step eliminates the noise, then the dilation makes the mask bigger. I actually did two dilations in a row, to create a nicer looking mask. [image]

I did a quick test in matlab as a proof of concept. I only used matlab because it was very quick (~5mins) to test, but I know openCV has very similar functions (dilation/erosion elements, imerode, imdilate). Read the code comments, there is some good information about the process. The code itself isn't important, and is included only for reference. The more important part is understanding what it does. I tried to match my "mask" to your mask, and I didn't use your outlined region at all.

```
segmented_im = rgb2gray(imread('binary_saturation_image.png'));
segmented_im = segmented_im(3:end,:);
orig_im = rgb2gray(imread('base_image.png'));

%i recreated your mask here, it looked like your mask had 0 values so thats
%what i used. it's 1 in region of interest and 0 elsewhere, this is
%important to take note of
mask = (segmented_im==0);

%creates a structuing element for our morphological operators, Another way
%to thing of this is like a nearest neighbor operation. This structuring
%element defines what your neighbors are, we are using a disk with radius 7
% in openCV this is your erosion/dilation element, the closest would be MORPH_ELLIPSE
%but using different elements and sizes may you get a better shape
%also using different shapes for the erosion vs dilation may help you
%further shape your mask
se = strel('disk',7,0);

%now we erode the image (this expands the 0 regions) we do this to remove
%noise, those small little dots around the mask
mask_erode = imerode(mask,se);

%now we dilate the image (expands the 1 regions) this will give us a more
%rounded mask
mask_dilate1 = imdilate(mask_erode,se);

%we do it one more time to round out the shape more
mask_dilate2 = imdilate(mask_dilate1,se);

%now we invert the mask (so the areas of interest are 0, and 1 elsewhere)
invert_mask = uint8(~mask_dilate2);

%we multiply the original image by our mask (so the area of interest has
%zero values)
newly_segmented = orig_im .* invert_mask;


figure()
subplot(2,3,1);imshow(orig_im);title('base image');
subplot(2,3,2);imshow(mask);title('mask');
subplot(2,3,3);imshow(mask_erode);title('mask erode image');
subplot(2,3,4);imshow(mask_dilate1);title('mask dilate1 image');
subplot(2,3,5);imshow(mask_dilate2);title('mask dilate2 image');
subplot(2,3,6);imshow(newly_segmented);title('newly segmented image');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since someone added this question to his favs, I'll post my best lead:

The best solution available for this kind of problem indeed seems to be **active contour segmentation**, for which I found [this Esnake implementation](http://bigwww.epfl.ch/algorithms/esnake/) from the Biomedical Imaging Group of the polytechnical school of Lausanne. It is an ImageJ plugin, but I hope to be able to implement it into my own app.